# Laravel Applying MySQL Scripts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my previous job, if you needed to update some records on their application, you created a sql script in the 'patches' folder, and once on deployment, a program would run all the new scripts in the folder. It was much like migrations, but it was for updating records, rather than just updating table structure. Does Laravel offer something similar to that? I looked up everywhere for this concept, outside of Laravel and failed to find something similar.

If one wants to automate updating some records in the production database, how does one do it? I know that I can manually run the scripts manually but I want some automation on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't [Laravel Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) what you are looking for?

You can easily create scripts for manipulation with database records and you can run them from CL via [Artisan](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/artisan).

Comment: It's similar to Laravel Migrations but it's different. Migrations is mostly used to update table structure, but I want to update records on a live database. Maybe, my thoughts about Laravel Migrations are incorrect, but would I use Laravel Migrations to update records?

Comment: I've used them for updates as well, and it worked out.

Comment: Okay, I'll use if for updating records. Thanks :)